# Invalid SAS topology

Tags: sas, topology, jbod

I have a 44-bay [Supermicro JBOD](https://www.supermicro.com/products/chassis/4U/847/SC847E1C-R1K28JBOD) which is connected to a MegaRAID 9280-8e. Upon boot, all drives show activity and the device scan reaches 100%. Then however, an eror message states:

> Invalid SAS topology, please check your cabling, fix and restart.

(Or something highly similar, this is from memory).

The RAID controller has proven to work on a different JBOD and I was unable to find any option in the RAID or system BIOS related to SAS topology, so I assume it has to be some issue with the JBOD.

I did the following steps to identify the problem:

1. I pulled all disks to verify it's not an issue caused by a single faulty drive. The error message remains identical ("Invalid SAS topology")
2. I verified the internal SAS cabling is accodring the backplanes manuals (IN -> backplane1 -> backplane2 -> IN/OUT).
3. Leaving the system running for a while, it repeatedly prints the "Invalid SAS topology" error but eventually continues and allows to enter the RAID configuration tool. Once there I see all disks and can even assemble RAID6 volumes. The volumes are still there on next boot, as is the error message "Invalid SAS topology".

I am quite puzzled and would be very grateful for any help or suggestions.

Comment: This one's got 'contact the vendor' written all over it sorry.

Comment: Yeah, this is a "Call Supermicro" situation

Comment: I am in touch with the vendor but they just keep sending me parts. Supermicro keeps pointing me to some BIOS settings which are just not there (not even in different words).